# Linux TCP blocking socket is returning zero with EAGAIN

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have a blocking TCP socket as a part of a TCP client implemented in C++. It is trying to read data using a `::read()` call on the socket descriptor. I am seeing very frequent cases, where the read returns with a value of 0, but the value of `errno` is `EAGAIN`.

**What is EAGAIN supposed to mean in case of blocking sockets?**

I understand the functioning in case of a non-blocking socket, but unclear about a blocking socket.

I understand it might be because of hitting a read timeout, but I am currently not setting a read timeout value.

**What is the default read timeout value in case of linux TCP sockets?**

Comment: `errno` is irrelevant unless the return value is -1. The meaning of a return value of zero is documented. It is not a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where the read returns with a value of 0

This means the peer has gracefully closed its end of the connection. You need to close your socket descriptor for that connection. Don't bother checking `errno`, it is meaningless in this condition. It only has meaning if `read()` had returned `< 0` instead.